# django-inplace edit remove hint at top

Tags: django, django-inplaceedit

I just started using the django-inplaceedit using latest version. It works great.

But I want to remove the hint that it shows when showing editable items  - 'Enable Edit Inline'. Is there any easy way to remove it?

BTW I searched the documentation for it is there way to reach mailing list associated with django-inplaceedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [relevant page](https://django-inplaceedit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) in the documentation, for anyone coming across this question in the future.

Look at the following code sample from that page in the documentation for putting the css for inplace-edit in the header, and the js in the body.

```
{% load inplace_edit %}
   <html>
       <head>
           ...
           {% inplace_css 1 %} {% comment %} or inplace_css 0 {% endcomment %}
       </head>
       <body>
           ...
           <div id="content">
               ...
               {% inplace_edit "content.name" %}
               ...
               <div class="description">
                   {% inplace_edit "content.date_initial|date:'d m Y'" %}
                   {% inplace_edit "content.description|safe" %}
               </div>
               <div class="body">
                   {% inplace_edit "content.body|safe|truncatewords_html:15" %}
               </div>
           </div>
           ...
           <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           {% inplace_js 1 1 %} {% comment %} or inplace_js 1 0 {% endcomment %}
       </body>
   </html>
```

simply replace `{% inplace_css 1 %}` with `{% inplace_css 0 %}` and `{% inplace_js 1 1 %}` with `{% inplace_js 1 0 %}` in the above example, and that should do the trick in v1.3.0 of inplaceedit.